# Cannot execute "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" Mysql query in Rails after a connection reconnection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

On Rails 2.3.8 (but I think Rails 3 might have this issue as well, not sure):

I get an error when trying to execute a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` query after reconnecting to a database.  I have a process that parses a file that can potentially take a bit of time.  During the parsing, Mysql closes the connection due to timeout.  This is fine, I do a `ActiveRecord::Base.verify_active_connections!` and I get the connection back (I do this in several places through my app).  However, running a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement, I get this error:

`Mysql::Error: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

It's **not** a permission issue, I know that for sure.  Check out my test in console:

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.infile' INTO TABLE users")
[Sat Jan 08 00:09:29 2011] (9990)   SQL (1.7ms)   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.infile' INTO TABLE users
 => nil

> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
 => #<Mysql:0x104c6f890>

> ActiveRecord::Base.verify_active_connections!
[Sat Jan 08 00:09:58 2011] (9990)   SQL (0.2ms)   SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0
 => {...connection stuff...} 

> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.infile' INTO TABLE users")
[Sat Jan 08 00:10:00 2011] (9990)   SQL (0.0ms)   Mysql::Error: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.infile' INTO TABLE users
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.infile' INTO TABLE users
    from ~/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:221:in `log'
    from ~/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:323:in `execute'
    from (irb):6
```

I am able to do other queries like `SELECT` and whatnot, and I will get the correct result.  It's just this one that giving me the error.  I even tested this with a fresh rails app.  You'll notice that I am able to do the exact same query *before* the disconnect.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm. The error message sounds fairly clear, doesn't it? Is this not more of a mySQL configuration / compilation / version issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [filed a ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6266-cannot-execute-mysql-load-data-infile-query-after-using-verify_active_connections#ticket-6266-12) with Rails and there's a solution offered on the ticket. Just going to have to wait for the Rails guys to patch this up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a [mySQL configuration issue](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data-local.html):

> If LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is disabled, either in the server or the client, a client that attempts to issue such a statement receives the following error message: 
>   ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"

see the linked page for various settings you need to check. One of them is likely to be set to disable the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command.

Comment: Hi Pekka, as stated in my question, I know this is not a permission issue.  The reason I know this is because I am able to do a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` before the reconnect (see my console output).  I can do that command several times in fact.  It's only **after** the reconnect that I get that error.

Comment: @Ngan ah, fair enough, I didn't catch that. That's different. How does the reconnect take place? Are you sure you are connecting to the same server? (Because that's the only way I can explain this)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the same server.  Just your typical reconnect.  You can easily duplicate this issue yourself.  Just create a new Rails project and do what I did in my console output.  I've filed a ticket with Rails, we'll see where that goes...