# Cannot execute “LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE” Mysql query in Rails 2.3.8 after a connection reconnection

Tags: mysql, activerecord

on MySqL config, local_infile is enabled as I could verify with: SHOW VARIABLES --> local_infile  ON.

But when I executed the following commands:

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

ActiveRecord::Base.verify_active_connections!

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'blalalla' INTO TABLE blababla")

I receive something like:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/tmp_stores.csv' INTO TABLE tmp_sztores

This topic is almost throughly (just the patch, no explanation) covered, at least at one existing questions: 4652330

[Cannot execute "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" Mysql query in Rails after a connection reconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652330/cannot-execute-load-data-local-infile-mysql-query-in-rails-after-a-connection?answertab=active#tab-top)

My questions is: why it happens when I call verify_active_connections!, therefore only when the connections are closed and then reconnected/connected again? Why it does work when the connection pool is initialized initially on establish_connection?

I have checked the code related with the method verify_active_connections! and it delegates to the MyslAdapter#reconnect! which calls the same 'connect' method...

I do not understand why after reconnection the local_infile flag should be explicitly set, otherwise it doesn't work.

Thank you!!!